# create or update dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Currently, I'm checking if the item exists with a query and then I'm using put or updateItem, I want to change it and make a single call to DDB. I want to make a query that will update or create item.

Here is a example of my item:

```
{
   id: 'dsfadsf'
   fa: { "apple" : { "S" : "76-100" }, "yolo" : { "S" : "0-25" }
   pa: { "finish" : { "BOOL" : false },    "userKey" : { "S" : "3e299e12-9e66" }  }
   createdAt: 32432432423
}
```

**item types:**

```
createdAt - Number
fa - Map
pa - Map
id - String
finish - Boolean
key - String
```

If item exists I want to push a new item like {papa: 'dsfadsf'} (never modify existing item inside fa Map) and modify finish value inside pa Map

This is the item after the update:

```
{
   id: 'dsfadsf'
   fa: { "apple" : { "S" : "76-100" }, "yolo" : { "S" : "0-25" }, "papa": { "S" : "dsfadsf"} }
   pa: { "finish" : { "BOOL" : true },    "userKey" : { "S" : "3e299e12-9e66" }  }
   createdAt: 32432432423
}
```

Here is what I tried and its not working

```
{
    TableName: tableName,
    Key: {
      id: "dsfadsf",
    },
    UpdateExpression: `SET #id = :id, fa.${itemName} = if_not_exists(fa.${itemName}, :text), pa.finish = if_not_exists(pa.finish, :finishval), #ca = :ca`,
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#id": "id",
      "#ca": createdAt
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":id": "7fd9a81b-7a7c-4cfb-9c84-25dc2798a8f7",
      ":text": itemText,
      ":finishval": true,
      ":ca": 32432432423
    },
    ConditionExpression: `attribute_not_exists(id)`,
  };
```

Comment: try this ConditionExpression: 'id = : id OR attribute_not_exists(id)'

Comment: I'm getting an error: "One or more parameter values were invalid: Cannot update attribute id. This attribute is part of the key"

Comment: This might be one of the reasons. Are the names and types of attributes same?

Comment: They are not the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TLDR

This isn't possible with the current structure of your item. Change `fa` & `pa` to be string sets, get rid of `finish: true` & use the ADD update expression.

---

This is not possible with the current structure of your item. Here's why — To meet your requirement, `UpdateExpression` needs to be of the form:

```
if "fa" exists, add {"papa":"dsfadsf"} to it
else, create new "fa"={"papa":"dsfadsf"}
```

Of all the [DynamoDB update expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html), only SET & ADD can be used in this scenario.

The above `if else` condition cannot be expressed in an `UpdateExpression` with SET due to the following reasons:

- `SET fa.papa = 'dsfadsf'` will update `fa` if it exists, but if it doesn't, you get the error `The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update`.
- `SET fa = {"papa":"dsfadsf"}` will create new `fa` but overwrite it if it exists.

If you try to combine ADD & SET to achieve the above `if else` condition, into something like `ADD fa {} SET fa.papa = dsfadsf`, you get the error `Two document paths overlap with each other; must remove or rewrite one of these paths`

So we're only left with the ADD expression now, but ADD only works on sets. So if you can afford to turn the contents of `fa` & `pa` into sets of strings, you can achieve your goal of "create or update in 1 go". Here's how it'll work:

The original item structure has to be:

```
{
  "ca": 32432432423,
  "fa": [
    "apple:76-100",
    "yolo:0-25"
  ],
  "id": "dsfadsf",
  "pa": [
    "key:9e66"
  ]
}
```

In DynamoDB JSON, that's:

```
{
  "ca": {
    "N": "32432432423"
  },
  "fa": {
    "SS": [
      "apple:76-100",
      "yolo:0-25"
    ]
  },
  "id": {
    "S": "dsfadsf"
  },
  "pa": {
    "SS": [
      "key:9e66"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, using the following code:

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk")
let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
docClient.update({
    TableName: "my-table",
    Key: { id: "dsfadsf" },
    UpdateExpression: `ADD fa :fa, pa :pa SET ca = :ca`,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":fa": docClient.createSet(["papa:dsfadsf"]),
        ":pa": docClient.createSet(["finished"]),
        ":ca": 32432432423
    }
}
```

If an item with the `id` "dsfadsf" already exists, it's updated as follows:

```
{
  "ca": {
    "N": "32432432423"
  },
  "fa": {
    "SS": [
      "apple:76-100",
      "papa:dsfadsf",
      "yolo:0-25"
    ]
  },
  "id": {
    "S": "dsfadsf"
  },
  "pa": {
    "SS": [
      "finished",
      "key:9e66"
    ]
  }
}
```

If an item with the `id` "dsfadsf" does NOT exist, it's created as follows:

```
{
  "ca": {
    "N": "32432432423"
  },
  "fa": {
    "SS": [
      "papa:dsfadsf"
    ]
  },
  "id": {
    "S": "dsfadsf"
  },
  "pa": {
    "SS": [
      "finished"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: how would this behave with concurrent updates to a string set, so in this case to `pa` or `fa`. Would all the updates be preserved?

Comment: Exellent answer. Very efficient to do those updates in a single transaction.